# Is it possible to trigger a redeployment from Heroku?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, git, heroku

I'm trying to get to a point where I can make and deploy emergency changes to my Heroku apps from mobile devices. Using CodeHub (ios) I'm able to make changes to the GitHib repo, and using Nezumi (ios) I'm able to access the logs, restart the application and even gain console access to my app. The one thing that I can't figure out how to do at the moment is how to push the updated GitHub repo to Heroku and rebuild/redeploy the slug.

Is there any way retrigger this via the heroku console or any other mobile friendly interface?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of deployment services that will do this, but if you're looking for one that works well on mobile, http://www.wercker.com is great.